# React build renders properly locally, but not for publishing. Build missing files/folders

Tags: reactjs, build, rendering, publish, snap

Using create react app-react 18 I can start in developer local preview, and build into local server. All pages/links work. But when I take that same build, which doesn't have all the populated pages visible and publish to server, almost all pages 404. Just home page works. I am missing most pages in the build, but they all work locally using server -s build from vs code after NPM run build. I'm thinking it has to do with react-snap.

[image: build from vs code]
[image: SRC]
[image: BuildText(should be 100+]
[image: BuildText]

JSON:

```json
{
    "name": "savethe",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.14",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.11.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "framer-motion": "^10.8.5",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "remixicon": "^3.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "xmlbuilder": "^15.1.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postbuild": "react-snap"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
    ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
    "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
    ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "react-snap": "^1.23.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
    }
}

"scripts": {
    "postbuild": "react-snap"
}
```

Change `src/index.js` (for React 16+):

```js
import { hydrate, render } from "react-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
if (rootElement.hasChildNodes()) {
    hydrate(<App />, rootElement);
} else {
    render(<App />, rootElement);
}
```

Tried different versions of react-snap. Importing snap to `index.js`. Downgrading to react 17 Change

Want to run build and publish, but it doesn't seem to build entire site that can be used to publish.

Comment: I noticed some questionable things about your JSON. Extra tabs/spaces at `"    xmlbuilder"` and `"    start"`, and a missing quote at `eject"`. If you fix these and it works, then this question should be closed as 'caused by typos.'

Comment: Sorry that is me trying to indent to allow me to post. Keyboard short cut not working properly. Those spaces/ quotes are fine in code"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postbuild": "react-snap"

Comment: I also suspect there are no backslashes before your `[` and `]` either.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and response. I confirmed the code for react-snap and made sure of the json file. There are no errors. I have tried uninstalling snap, using snapshot, using different versions of snap, updating puppeteer, moving snap code between index.js and app.js. I get same result. It builds, but only 32 out of 100+ pages when using react-snap 1.23. Previous snap versions build no pages.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Links before all my Routes fixed this.

I have other projects running same dependencies that didn't require this so I am still not sure why this fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).